# Is an Atom N2600 64-bit or 32-bit?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

I'm looking at an Intel spec sheet. It says that the processor has a 64-bit instruction set. However, running:

```
uname -m
```

results in `i686`, and running:

```
grep flags /proc/cpuinfo
```

indicates that each processor has a `tm` flag and not an `lm` flag.

Does this processor support 64-bit operating systems? If not, what's the difference between what's being said and what is actually the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The official Intel specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/58916/Intel-Atom-Processor-N2600-%281M-Cache-1_6-GHz%29) indicate that the processor is 64-bit.

However, you are running a 32-bit operating system, which explains `i686` and the absence of the `lm` ([long mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode)—the 64-bit operating mode of an x86-64 processor) flag.  `tm` refers to thermal monitor support and has nothing to do with 64-bit support.

In your case, it looks like the manufacturer of the computer has disabled 64-bit support, which means you probably need to purchase another computer to be able to install a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: I tried installing a 64 bit operating system. It failed because the cpu was not somehow marked as "x86_64".

Comment: Is your BIOS configured to enable 64-bit support?

Comment: It says EMT64 is not supported. http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/332640-28-emt64-intel-atom-n2600

Answer (score 1):

I have an Asus eeePC 1025c.  It has an atom N2600, but will not boot a 64bit OS.  According to this forum thread, the manufacturer has disabled it in the BIOS: http://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-REQUEST-Asus-eeepc-1025C.

I didn't try to flash the replacement, but at least I know why I'm stuck with 32bit processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can flash the bios for the Asus eee pc X101CH with Atom N2600 to 64-bit:
https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-ASUS-X101CH-EMT64-Request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1131419)